# Integral related to poisson kernel on the Unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I encountered the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{1-2xcos(t)+x^2} \,dt \,dx $$

This looks somewhat familiar to the poisson kernel. However I had trouble utilizing that in order to check for convergence. Hence my question is if this Integral converges, and if so, where to.

thanks in advance

Comment: Use the substitution $s=\tan\frac t2$, and you will get, integrating with respect to $s$
$$I(\alpha)=2\pi\int_0^\alpha\frac{dx}{1-x^2},\,\alpha\to1$$
This addresses you question about convergence.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me how this substitution leads you to this integral. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{1-2x\cos(t)+x^2} \,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{1+x^2-2x(2\cos^2\frac t2-1)}$$
$$\overset{\tan\frac t2=s}{=}2\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{(1+x)^2(1+s^2)-4x}+\frac1{(1+x)^2(1+s^2)-4xs^2}\right)ds$$